# Make sure some fields are there in a configuration file (for the Atom IDE) via a Ansible playbook

Tags: json, ansible, yaml, atom-editor

I am trying to install and configure the Atom Editor IDE using Ansible.
I know how to retrieve and parse a JSON file with Ansible, but **I don't see how to insert/update some fields of that JSON file when seen as a dictionary**, also dealing with the fact that the file may not be there at the beginning of the Ansible workbook.

I know the settings are stored in `~/.atom/config.cson`.

My initial configuration looked like this:

```
$ cat ~/.atom/config.cson 
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    invisibles: {}
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "<SOME_UUID>"
```

But then I wanted to make sure tabs were treated as 2 blank spaces, so I went on the Settings window, changed some parameters and then the configuration file looked like:

```
$ cat ~/.atom/config.cson 
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    invisibles: {}
    showInvisibles: true
    softTabs: false
    tabType: "soft"
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "<SOME_UUID>"
```

In Ansible I know I can load a JSON object and parse it with:

```
  - name: Configure Atom IDE
    shell: cat /home/"{{ cli_input_username }}"/.atom/config.cson
    register: result
    become_user: "{{ cli_input_username }}"
  - set_fact:
      atom_config_dict: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"
```

And then inspect some fields of that "JSON dictionary" with `"{{ jsonVar['atom_config_dict."*".editor'] }}"`. I think this is going to work, but it may be I need to use some special tricks because of that asterisk used as a key of the dictionary `"*"`.

But then **how do I UPSERT (INSERT/UPDATE JSON key/values) some fields and save to file the whole JSON dictionary (after the changes) at `~/.atom/config.cson`**?

Do I have to treat special JSON keys as `"*"` in a specific way? Or is it just a string treated as a key of the dictionary?

How do I make sure the Ansible playbook can handle the fact that the configuration JSON file may not be there at the beginning? (e.g. when I am installing the Atom Editor IDE for the first time, i.e. at the first execution of the Ansible playbook).

**EDIT**:

I just realised this configuration file may not be an entirely valid JSON. In fact that file extension is "cson" which I am not familiar with.
So probably those tricks regarding `from_json` won't work.

Is there a way to deal with this configuration file in a structured way in order to make it searchable and parse it and then inser/update some keys of that dictionary? Perhaps this could be treated as a YAML file using `from_yaml`?

Comment: You're right, Atom uses CSON (CoffeeScript Object Notation) instead of JSON - this is probably not going to work.

Comment: In your place, I would rather provide the file either as a template (solves the case the that the file is not there yet), or using something like `blockinfile` to add what you want to add.

Comment: Yep, thanks for that CSON detail, I've updated the title of the question to remove the JSON mention. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Atom works perfectly with a JSON file that stores your configuration. Simply convert the existing `config.cson` to JSON, delete (or rename) the file and place the converted `config.json` in its place.

To convert the file, you could use [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/) (requires little editing) or the [atomizr](https://atom.io/packages/atomizr) package for Atom. With the latter installed, simply open your `config.cson` and run the *Atomizr: Toggle Atom Format* command. Note that with the default settings, this will not keep the original file.

Comment: Thanks but then how do I make sure the configuration file contains a given structure? This whole thing is supposed to be configured in an automated way, trying to have reproducible installations and environment setup e.g. all these atom plugins could be installed using `apm` in an Ansible task, but then I should be able to run the conversion without manual intervention.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. I thought you already knew how to write JSON in Ansible, but not CSON.